# Database design for saving statistics and also saving the history of the statistic

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I'm currently working on a project where I want to save statistics of a user. Let's just assume, I'm saving statistics of his Facebook-Page. (Page-Likes, Comment-Count on all posts of the current day, Share-Count on all posts of the current day.

The thing is, that I want to save the counts, but also save the data as history in a sperate table. I also want to have the `min/max` values of these values.

Now the problem I'm having is the following. Where exactly would I save the data of the current day, where would I save the max/min values? Would I save the most recent data including `max/min/current` values into the table `facebook_pages` and also saving into `facebook_history`?

Now I have several scenarios

**Scenario 1: Saving the most recent data in one table**

```
//Table 1: facebook_pages

id
facebook_page_id  
page_likes  
page_likes_MAX
page_likes_MIN
post_likes  
post_likes_MAX
post_likes_MIN
post_shares
post_shares_MAX
post_shares_MIN   
post_comments
post_comments_MAX
post_comments_MIN

//Table 2: facebook_history

id
facebook_pages_id (referencing the id on the table facebook_pages)
page_likes
post_likes
post_shares
post_comments
checkDate (date when the data got gathered)
```

Here, it would be simple. When I want all data of a user, I just had to run a query

```
"SELECT * FROM facebook_pages WHERE id = {ID}";
```

**SCENARIO 2: Saving only max/min values into one table**

```
//Table 1: facebook_pages

id
facebook_page_id  
page_likes_MAX
page_likes_MIN
post_likes_MAX
post_likes_MIN
post_shares_MAX
post_shares_MIN   
post_comments_MAX
post_comments_MIN

//Table 2: facebook_history

id
facebook_pages_id (referencing the id on the table facebook_pages)
page_likes
post_likes
post_shares
post_comments
checkDate (date when the data got gathered)
```

This one is also simple (care, it's only pseudocode here)

```
"SELECT * FROM facebook_pages INNER JOIN facebook_history
WHERE id = {ID} AND checkDate = {TODAY}";
```

**Scenario 3: Saving only the history and querying Max/Min when data is needed**

```
//Table 1: facebook_pages

id
facebook_page_id  
page_likes  
post_likes  
post_shares
post_comments

//Table 2: facebook_history

id
facebook_pages_id (referencing the id on the table facebook_pages)
page_likes
post_likes
post_shares
post_comments
checkDate (date when the data got gathered)
```

This one here is also simple. Just querying the ID and then selecting with `MAX` and `MIN` functions of MySQL.

As you can see, all of the above scenarios are simple. What I am just thinking is, which one is the best?

From a database engineer point of view? From a logical point of view? Which scenario makes the most sense?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you would only need one table with the "raw" collected data + a timestamp (a simpler version of Scenario 3). You can then query from that table with your min/max aggregates grouped on whole dates. You don't have redundancy then (good).

If the table grow big and the query gets slow, you can put an index on the timestamp column, if that also gets too slow, you can introduce redundancy by creating a new table with aggregates which you populate with your query each night and then query that table from your application.